# sql: trouble with where clause

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| P33 | x |
| P33 | y |
| P22 | x |
| N44 | y |
| D99 | null |

I need to select all the values in Column A that do not have 'x' and 'y' in Column B, and the ones that have null in the second table. So the result should look like this:

| Result |
| --- |
| P22 |
| N44 |
| D99 |

Comment: Is there a question, too? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Show us your current query, and I'm sure someone can help you out.

Comment: Please tag your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that account for duplicities in the count and works with null.

```
select   [Column A]
        
from     t

group by [Column A]

having   count(case [Column B] when 'x' then 1 end) = 0 
      or count(case [Column B] when 'y' then 1 end) = 0
```

| Column A |
| --- |
| D99 |
| N44 |
| P22 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60f545186b85e50b932f305ec508e590&hide=1)

Comment: See updated answer for same logic with cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
    select t.columna from table1 t
    where  columnb in ('x','y')
    having count(distinct Columnb)<2
     group by t.columna 
   union all
   select t.columna from table1 t
   where columnb is null and columnb not in ('x','y')
```

Comment: your code will not work having comes always after group by and a group by will ignore NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can use two anti-joins. For example:

```
select a.column_a
from t a
left join t x on x.column_a = a.column_a and x.column_b = 'x'
left join t y on y.column_a = a.column_a and y.column_b = 'y'
where x.column_a is null or y.column_a is null
```

Comment: It should be OR instead of AND

Answer (score 0):

This is mySQL ver5.6.

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM (
  SELECT 
   ColumnA,
   GROUP_CONCAT(ColumnB ORDER BY ColumnB) as ColumnXY
FROM 
   table1
GROUP BY
   ColumnA
  ) table2
WHERE ColumnXY <> 'x,y' OR ColumnXY is NULL;
```